# OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers] while integrating UIKIT and COCCOS2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I am trying to integrate UIView to a simple  hello world Coccos2d project.Im actually following the following tutorial
 http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit
,but I'm getting this error  OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers].Can any one help?

Comment: Where are you adding the view? can u post some code ??

Comment: Which version of cocos2d are you using? That tutorial is from september 2011.

Comment: cocco2 2d version 1.0

Comment: thanks Hamadullah actually i was not adding window and was calling it,it was a silly mistake from my side..thanks guys..